# Appengine runs a stale version of the code -- and stack traces don't match source code

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a python27 appengine application. My application generates a 500 error early in the code initialization, and I can inspect the stack trace in the StackDriver debugger in the GCP console.

I've since patched the code, and I've re-deployed under the same service name and version name (i.e. `gcloud app deploy --version=SAME`). Unfortunately, the old error still comes up, and line numbers in the stack traces reflect the files in the buggy deployment. If I use the code viewer to debug the error, I am however brought to the updated patched code in the online viewer -- and there is a mismatch. It behave as if the app instance is holding on to a previous snapshot of the code.

I'm fuzzy on the freshness and eventual consistency guarantees of GAE. Do I have to wait to get everything to serve the latest deployed version? Can I force it to use the newer code right away?

*Things I've tried:*

I initially assumed the problem had to do with versioning, i.e. maybe requests being load-balanced between instances with the same version, but each with slightly different code. I'm a bit fuzzy on the actual rules that govern which GAE instance gets chosen for a new request (esp whether GAE tries to reuse previous instances based on a source IP). I'm also fuzzy on whether or not active instances get destroyed right away when different code is redeployed under the same version name.

To take that possibility out of the equation, I tried pushing to a new version name, and then deleting all previous versions (using `gcloud app versions list` to get the list). But it doesn't help -- I still get stack traces from the old code, despite the source being up to date in the GCP console debugger. Waiting a couple hours doesn't do anything either.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve (or avoid) by not changing the version?

Comment: Thanks. I've added some clarification. It seemed like an easy thing to try. I'm fuzzy on the consistency guarantees wrt versioning and wanted to cover more bases. I'm not super familiar with how GAE assigns instances to incoming requests, nor am I certain if GAE allows active instances with the same version id but different code to co-exist at any given time. Now that I know the [actual cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57047713/5556676), I realize that those tests were probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried two things:

1. disabling and re-enabling the application in GAE->Settings
2. I'd also noticed that there were some .pyc files uploaded in the snapshot, so I removed those and re-deployed.

I discovered that (1) is a very effective way to stop all running appengine instances. When you deploy a new version of a project, a traffic split is created (i.e. 0% for the old version and 100% for the new), but in my experience old instances might still be running if they've been used recently (despite them being configured to receive 0% of traffic). Toggling kills them all *immediately*. I unfortunately found that my stale code was still being used after re-enabling.

(2) did the trick. It wasn't obvious that .pyc were being uploaded. I discovered it by looking at `GCP->StackDriver->Debug` and I saw .pyc files in the tree snapshot.

I had recently updated my `.gitignore` to ignore locally installed pip runtime dependencies for the project (output of `pip install -t lib requirements.txt`). I don't want those in git, but they do need to ship as part of my appengine project. I had removed the `#!.gitignore` special include line from `.gcloudignore`. However, I forgot to re-add `*.pyc` into my .gcloudignore.

Another way to see the complete set of files included in an app deployment is to increase the verbosity to `info` on the gcloud app deploy command -- you see a giant json manifest with checksums. I don't typically leave that on because it's hard to visually inspect, but I would have spotted the .pyc in there.

Comment: You may want to add to the `.gcloudignore` file the default patterns from the [`skip_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) app.yaml option (I don't know of documented defaults for `.gcloudignore`). They would have covered the `.pyc` files.